# How do I add the error message for BMI calculator fields next/under them instead of on the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, field

So I'm trying to get the error message to go next to the field, but I have no idea what I'm doing, I'm pretty new at this, sorry to bother you guys.

Here's the whole code:

```js
function computeBMI() {

  var height = 0;
  var weight = 0;
  height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
  weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
  if (height == 0 | height > 220) {
    document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = "Use Appropriate Height";
    return 0;
  }
  if (weight == 0 | weight < 20) {
    document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = "Use Appropriate Weight";
    return 0;
  }

  var BMI = weight / (height / 100 * height / 100);
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;
  var output = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;
  if (output < 18.5)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Underweight";
  else if (output >= 18.5 && output <= 25)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Normal";
  else if (output > 25)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Overweight";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>BMI Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="errorMsg"></div>
  <h1>Body Mass Index Calculator</h1>
  <p>Enter your height: <input type="text" id="height" /></p> <span id="errorMsg"><
<p>Enter your weight: <input type="text" id="weight"/></p>

<input type="submit" value="computeBMI" onclick="computeBMI();">
<h1>Your BMI is: <span id="output">?</span></h1>

  <h2>This means you are: <span id="comment"> ?</span> </h2>
</body>
```

Comment: An html id must be unique and there are 2 #errorMsg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it your way you would need a separate error message area next to each input, and each one would need a unique ID - currently you have two elements whose ID is "errorMsg", one of which is in the wrong place in the layout. An ID must (by definition) uniquely identify an element, so clearly that isn't going to work. When you refer to "errorMsg" in your code, JavaScript will just pick the first one it finds and assume you meant that one. It has no way of telling them apart.

But anyway for the validation you're trying to do, you don't actually need to write your own code at all. If you put your fields inside a form, and handle the submit event of the form, you can then use HTML5 validation rules on the fields themselves to restrict the allowed input.

Here's a demo:

Note the addEventListener to handle the "submit" event of the form and run some Javascript.
Note also the `<form>` and `</form>` tags round the fields and button, and lastly the `type="number"`, `required`, `min` and `max` attributes on the input fields themselves.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("BMIForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); //stop a postback
 computeBMI();
});

function computeBMI() {

  var height = 0;
  var weight = 0;
  height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
  weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);

  var BMI = weight / (height / 100 * height / 100);
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;
  var output = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;

  if (output < 18.5)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Underweight";
  else if (output >= 18.5 && output <= 25)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Normal";
  else if (output > 25)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Overweight";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>BMI Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Body Mass Index Calculator</h1>
  <form id="BMIForm">
  <p>Enter your height: <input type="number" required min="0" max="220" id="height" /></p>
  <p>Enter your weight: <input type="number" required min="0" max="20" id="weight"/></p>

<input type="submit" value="computeBMI">
</form>
<h1>Your BMI is: <span id="output">?</span></h1>

 <h2>This means you are: <span id="comment"> ?</span> </h2>
</body>
```

You can learn more about HTML form validation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Thank you very much! There's still a problem though, although the errors work, the calculator itself stopped working, here's what I have now
https://pastebin.pl/view/34731921

Comment: As you can see if you run my demo, what I've written definitely works. Look carefully for differences between your version and mine. You left a stray `function computeBMI()
    {` at the top of your page, for one thing. Open your browser's Developer Tools (press F12) when you're on the page and check for errors. Attention to detail is an important skill for a programmer, as is learning to use the developer tools for debugging and error checking.

Comment: Also you need to write your intitial script in a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { .. });` block otherwise it'll run before the form is rendered on the page, and the event listener won't be attached. Either that or you can move the `<script` block to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Will do, thank you so much for the help! I will try and train myself to noticing the little details, I really appreciate it, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use an element's ID, but you can only select one element using ID. You have to use class, and then select which element in the satisfying list of elements contain the class you want.

Also, I updated your code a little bit so instead of validating if the answer fits in an anti-category, it checks if it does not fit in a specified category.

```js
function computeBMI() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('errorMsg')[0].innerHTML = ""
  document.getElementsByClassName('errorMsg')[1].innerHTML = ""
  var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
  var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
  var returnVal = false
  if (!(height > 0 && height <= 220)) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('errorMsg')[0].innerHTML = "Use Appropriate Height";
    returnVal = returnVal || true
  }
  if (!(weight > 0 && weight < 20)) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('errorMsg')[1].innerHTML = "Use Appropriate Weight";
    returnVal = returnVal || true
  }
  if (returnVal) {
    return 0
  }

  var BMI = weight / (height / 100 * height / 100);
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;
  var output = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;
  if (output < 18.5)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Underweight";
  else if (output >= 18.5 && output <= 25)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Normal";
  else if (output > 25)
    document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Overweight";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>BMI Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Body Mass Index Calculator</h1>
  Enter your height:
  <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="height" />
  <span class="errorMsg"></span><br> Enter your weight:
  <input type="text" id="weight" placeholder="weight" />
  <span class="errorMsg"></span><br>

  <input type="submit" value="computeBMI" onclick="computeBMI();">
  <h1>Your BMI is: <span id="output">?</span></h1>

  <h2>This means you are: <span id="comment"> ?</span> </h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Whilst your code may work correctly, code-only answers are not encouraged here - especially when directed at beginners. Otherwise you're just expecting people to just blindly copy/paste without understanding. To make a good-quality answer, you should explain what exactly you've changed, and more important _why_ you changed it. Then everyone can learn from it as well as use it. And that way they can re-apply the same concepts in future and not need to ask about it again.